# ASP.NET Core Error - When Index() Method is updated

Tags: asp.net-core

IN my ASP.NET Core web application in the Controller I did a code change as shown below:

My initial Index method

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.ClientApplications.ToListAsync());
}
```

I wanted to have the code as ordinarry ASP.NET MVC code without async operations. so changed it.
My change:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Now I get an error

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object. AspNetCore.Views_Applications_Index.ExecuteAsync() in
>   Index.cshtml, line 25

The full error is as below:

> AspNetCore.Views_Applications_Index.ExecuteAsync() in Index.cshtml
>   @foreach (var item in Model) {
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage
>   page, ViewContext context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage
>   page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext
>   viewContext, string contentType, Nullable statusCode)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
>   actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData,
>   ITempDataDictionary tempData, string contentType, Nullable
>   statusCode)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
>   context, ViewResult result)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult
>   result)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref
>   bool isCompleted)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext
>   context) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref
>   State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)

Comment: The error came from your `Index.cshtml` file, line 25. Not with that method.

Comment: @Tân Oh snap a silly mistake from my part. A null exception during the for loop in the view. Now I pass the model data to the view works fine. Thank you ! If you could add it as an answer, then I could up-vote !

Comment: in your change you removed your parameter of the View, the parameter would be used as model in your view. Can you post cshtml code? my guess is you don't have a null check against your model in your view file